# Exercise in Lebesgue integration.

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

Find
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} e^{-2|x| \left( 1+ \frac{\arctan(nx)}{\pi} \right)}dx.
$$

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that we have $$e^{-2|x|\left(1+\frac{\arctan(nx)}{\pi}\right)}\le e^{-|x|}$$

and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-|x|}\,dx<\infty$.  Therefore, the dominated convergence theorem guarantees that

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-2|x|\left(1+\frac{\arctan(nx)}{\pi}\right)}\,dx&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \lim_{n\to \infty}\left(e^{-2|x|\left(1+\frac{\arctan(nx)}{\pi}\right)}\right)\,dx\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-2|x|\left(1+\frac12\text{sgn}(x)\right)}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{x}\,dx+\int_0^\infty e^{-3x}\,dx\\\\
&=1+\frac13\\\\
&=\frac43
\end{align}$$